# Powershell error with PnPOnline when trying to use ClientId and ClientSecret to connect to SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell

I am using PnPOnline to connect to SharePointOnline in order to publish files there from local network. I have installed PnpOnline and set up everything, but I'm getting this error when trying to simply connect (lol, stuck at the first step :( )

[image: Code]

This is what I'm running. But when I run it, this is the error I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see I'm stuck in the first step. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How do I resolve this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the latest version 1.11.0 of the module "PnP.PowerShell" ?

Comment: Doh!!! That was it. Install-module pnp.powershell